# postgres memory performance vs sharedfileset in pgsql_tmp directory

Tags: postgresql, performance, database-performance, temporary-files

We are running a postgres cluster with 32 CPU and 84 GB RAM in production with db size close to ~800GB.
It has replica setup as well with streaming wall replication (another host) kept as hot-standby.

```
Linux 2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64 (CentOS 6.4, upgrade pending)
Postgres Version - 11.11
```

We see some weird behaviour since last month with our instance having memory usage going every 80 hours even without having any cronjobs running at the specified moment (usually cron setup works `specified-time/hourly/daily/weekly/monthly`).
At the same time we see huge(~70gb) of temp files , e.g `pgsql_tmp90128.0.sharedfileset/i231326of1048576.p2.0`) being created and not getting deleted even after the postgres started working fine after 10 minutes.

My related settings for postgres memory utilization are following

```
work_mem         8 MB
temp_buffers     8 MB
shared_buffers  22 GB
max_connections  2500
```

During the window we see system cpu shoots up and came down again once memory refreshes.

```
$ sar -f /var/log/sa/sa17 -s 08:36:00 -e 08:47:00
>
08:36:21 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
08:37:21 AM     all     18.66      0.01     26.05      9.54      0.00     45.74
08:38:21 AM     all      5.21      0.01     81.71      2.11      0.00     10.96
08:39:21 AM     all      2.71      0.01     96.90      0.04      0.00      0.34
08:40:08 AM     all      1.55      0.00     98.44      0.00      0.00      0.00
08:41:08 AM     all      9.96      0.02     38.49      2.20      0.00     49.34
08:42:08 AM     all      0.12      0.00      1.50      1.63      0.00     96.74
08:43:08 AM     all      0.10      0.01      1.32      1.79      0.00     96.79
08:44:08 AM     all      0.20      0.01      2.25      0.76      0.00     96.79
08:45:08 AM     all      1.74      0.01      1.83      5.89      0.00     90.53
08:46:08 AM     all     10.09      0.01      7.37     18.90      0.00     63.63
Average:        all      5.11      0.01     34.18      4.36      0.00     56.34
```

RAM usage pattern

```
$ sar -r -f /var/log/sa/sa17 -s 08:36:00 -e 08:47:00
>
08:36:21 AM kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit
08:37:21 AM    430888  88277480     99.51     12176  23869496  79753764     87.83
08:38:21 AM    420612  88287756     99.53      7212  23425316  80174100     88.29
08:39:21 AM    424276  88284092     99.52      3552  23246368  81653952     89.92
08:40:08 AM    417172  88291196     99.53      4316  22819904  82023344     90.33
08:41:08 AM  84692800   4015568      4.53    978760   1124852  25077588     27.62
08:42:08 AM  78749436   9958932     11.23   2098912   1139416  25067128     27.61
08:43:08 AM  73598564  15109804     17.03   3065228   1140756  25067516     27.61
08:44:08 AM  70213124  18495244     20.85   3175984   1141168  25067016     27.61
08:45:08 AM  56661972  32046396     36.13   3179640  13233168  27063188     29.80
08:46:08 AM  30585252  58123116     65.52   3207036  30364932  32130264     35.38
Average:     39619410  49088958     55.34   1573282  14150538  48307786     53.20
```

I have the following questions in this respect:

- What can be the probable cause of this behaviour of memory usage going dropped at regular interval ?
- What these temp_files are and is it safer to delete manually ?
- Is there a bug in Postgres, why it's not getting automatically
  cleaned, [related-thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20191212180506.GR2082@telsasoft.com)

I see several run of [CHECKPOINT](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-what-is-a-checkpoint/) and even then the temp files are not getting cleared.

Comment: Look in the log file for messages from around that time.